# How can I check the value in another python file when I debug this python file?

Tags: python, debugging, pytorch

I an running a trainer.py. Now I want to check one term of my loss function. But the loss function is define in a Class in another .py
The training section of maintraining.py is as the below,

```
for data in tqdm(train_loader):
    trainer.train_step(data)
```

While the trainer.train_step is defined in another .py, which is as the below:

```
class DVTrainer(Trainer):
      def __init__(.....)

      def _train_step(self, data):
          loss = self._compute_loss(data)
          self.opt.zero_grad()
          loss.backward()
          self.opt.step()
      def _compute_loss(self,data):
          x, y, _ = data
          p_z_given_x = self.encoder(x)
          z = p_z_given_x.rsample()
          q_x_given_z = self.decoder(z)
          KL_loss = p_z_given_x.log_prob(z) + self.prior.log_prob(z)
```

Now I run the maintraining.py, but I wanna check the value and size of KL_loss when I debug the maintraing.py. I'm searching for a long time on net.But no use. Please help or try to giver some ideas how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: KL_loss is defined as a local variable of the `_compute_loss()` method - so it only exists during the execution of the method, i.e. when the first line of `_train_step()` is being executed. It's unclear what you mean when you say "I wanna check the value and size of KL_loss when I debug the maintraing.py" - it only exists briefly, so you could just set a breakpoint on that line?

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a try. But I have another question that when I set a breakpoint on this line, should I step into the trainer.train_step function and then run the code in the trainer.train_step again?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the debugging process, so I may have some seemingly simple questions.